# Achieving Rest using Angularjs and Java

Tags: java, angularjs, web-services, rest

I am a Angularjs Intermediate learner looking forward to learn REST web services in Angularjs using Java as backend language, But googled through many websites I couldn't get a clear view of how to achieve REST Web services By taking AngularJs as a frontend and Java as a backend.Moreover, I am getting raw content which can't get any idea of it.

So Which framework should I go with if it's java as a backend ?

And do I need to use any database for Rest web service ?

Comment: welcome to Stackoverflow. When you are asking questions in Stackoverflow please try to stick to specific problems that you may be facing. There are plenty of tutorials which are available all over the internet which demonstrates the usage of $http in Angular.JS and creating REST based Webservice in Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think you should change the way you think. Angularjs will work with any rest no matter its back-end lagnuage. Angularjs can preform all the rest operations using `$http`. You can check the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) for this purpose here.

For the Java Part. I think you should get deep in JAVA EE. Although my personal recommendation is to try to learn more new technologies like : Node.js , ASP.net , Python and PHP, as JAVA EE is not that popular these days.

Answer (score 0):

May be you should go through this 
[Spring and Angular Js](https://spring.io/blog/2015/01/12/spring-and-angular-js-a-secure-single-page-application)

Comment: Thanks masSdev , but the put method in that article is creating for only static data or value . So how to achieve for dynamic data or transaction. Where shall i store the dynamic data ?

Comment: can you copy that code i cant find the put method you are talking about!

Comment: !doctype html>
<html ng-app="demo">
 <head>
  <title>Hello AngularJS</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
     <script src="hello.js"></script>
 </head>

 <body>
  <div ng-controller="Hello">
   <p>The ID is {{greeting.id}}</p>
   <p>The content is {{greeting.content}}</p>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>

Comment: In this {{greeting.id}} is a static content or data right ?

Comment: No its your scope object which may contain static or dynamic content!!